# making a div "hug" its contained components

Tags: html, css

If I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="figure">
  <img src="some_image.png" />
  <div><span class="caption">Fig. 1: Some caption</span></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use CSS so that the `div` with class `figure` has a width that is only large enough to contain the image and caption? I want to put a rectangular border around both, but I don't want to have to guess the div's width in pixels.

example below (`div.figure` has a width that seems to expand to fill its available width)

```css
div.figure { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png?v=6f86a5fa447f" />
<div><span class="caption">Fig. 1: Some caption</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

A `<div>` is a block-level element *(Same as HTML5 figure tag)*. So you need to specify you want an inline-block behavior adding the css property `display: inline-block;` to your figure.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
figure {
  border: 1px inset tomato;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="my-photo"/>
  <figcaption>
    Fig. 1: Some caption
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

**FURTHER READING:**

[How well do you know CSS display?](https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/how-well-do-you-know-display/#????) by Chen Hui Jing - June 18, 2016

[Display](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) by Sara Cope - March 16, 2015

Comment: another option is to `display: table` +1

Answer (score 4):

Since `div`s are block elements by default, all you need to do is add `display: inline-block;` to `div.figure`. Like so:

```css
div.figure { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png?v=6f86a5fa447f" />
<div><span class="caption">Fig. 1: Some caption</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.figure {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Its pretty self explanatory though, Width auto states.. its automatic. The inline block is doing the work though. It tells it to only be the width of its children. so more can fit "inline" with it.

Comment: what's the default width, if you don't put `width: auto` ?

Comment: For inline-block elements the default width is auto so you don't need to specify it, divs will be placed next to each other until they no longer fit horizontally and will break into another line. For block level elements width is 100% by default, divs will be placed vertically after each other.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do this is to simply add `float: left`, which floats the div next of elements near it. A `float` also makes it so a div is only as wide as it's content (Unless otherwise specified).